# Prediction and forecasting with Python tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I have created a prediction model and used RNN in it offered by the tensorflow library in Python. Here is the complete code I have created and tried:

[Jupyter Notbook of the Code](https://github.com/JafferWilson/test-tensorflow/blob/master/Currency_Market_Predictor_RNN.ipynb)

But I have doubts.
1) Whether RNN is correct for what I am trying to predict?

2) Is there a better algorithm I can try?

3) Can anyone suggest me how I can give multiple inputs and get the necessary output using tensorflow model? Can anyone guide me please.

I hope I am clear on my points. Please do tell me if anything else required.

Comment: You should include the code in the question though! Or at least pinpoint the parts you have trouble with.

Comment: @Eypros Well I guess I have added the code. If you want then I will add the complete jupyter notebook if you have trouble in opening the jupyter. The code what bit bigger and with execution. Hence I have added the jupyter notebook for clearer understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Having doubts is normal, but you should try to measure them before asking for advice. If you don't have a clear thing you want to improve it's unlikely you will get something better.

> 1) Whether RNN is correct for what I am trying to predict?

Yes. RNN is used appropriately here. If you don't care much about having arbitrary length input sequences, you can also try to force them to a fixed size and then apply convolutions on top (see convolutional NeuralNetworks), or even try with a more simple DNN.

The more important question to ask yourself is if you have the right inputs and if you have sufficient training data to learn what you hope to learn.

> 2) Is there a better algorithm I can try?

Probably no. As I said RNN seems appropriate for this problem. Do try some hyper parameter tuning to make sure you don't accidentally just pick a sub-optimal configuration.

> 3) Can anyone suggest me how I can give multiple inputs and get the necessary output using tensorflow model? Can anyone guide me please.

The common way to handle variable length inputs is to set a max length and pad the shorter examples until they reach that length. The max length can be a variable you pick or you can dynamically set it to the largest length in the batch. This is needed only because the internal operations are done in batches. You can pick which results you want. Picking the last one is reasonable (the model will just have to learn to propagate the state for the padding values). Another reasonable thing to do is to pick the first one you get after feeding the last meaningful value into the RNN.

Looking at your code, there's one thing I would improve:

Instead of computing a loss on the last value only, I would compute it over all values in the series. This gives your model more training data with very little performance degradation.

Comment: `Instead of computing a loss on the last value only, I would compute it over all values in the series. This gives your model more training data with very little performance degradation.` Sir can you suggest me what exactly I need to add?

Comment: Sir also I wanted to know what you mean by inputs? according to me the inputs are the column values. I am not considering only one column, but more than one column as you might see that in the code. Please let me know what you suggest.